# Woocommerce Apply Price To Attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**I have a Woocommerce product with a lot of attributes field.**

***Lets take this as an example:***
I have a shop that sells engraved stones, there can be a maximum of 10 letters on each stone. There are 26 letters in the alphabet. The stone it self costs 3$ with 0 letters engraved, each letter(attribute) has its on custom price. The letter 'A' adds 0.25$ to the price, the letter 'B' however adds 0.30$ to the price. So now you see I get a lot of variation possibilities(variation) and it is time consuming work to type each price for each possibility(variation).

I was wondering if there is any plugin or PHP code out there that lets me add a price to the attribute instead of the variation itself.

Example:
I would go to the attribute page and select a attribute and enter the price there so now the letter 'A' is globally singed to add 0.25$ to the price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Woocommerce has a plugin called [Variable Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) that allows you to set different attributes for any product and manage the characteristics of each variation.